# Relative paths of images contained in an ajax aspx page

Tags: asp.net, iis

In my webapp, I have a folder Views. In this folder several .aspx pages live. I don't use the rendered contents directly in the webapp, rather I request the contents using ajax in a main aspx page on the root of the webapp.

Now when I refer to an image, "images/image.png" will work since the image reference lives in the aspx page on the root. When I change this to "/images/image.png", this won't work since the root is determined by the virtual IIS folder.

How can I have a clean reference e.g. "/images/image.png"?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly and probably most elegant, make the element run at the server and use the root-reletive url:

```
<img src="~/images/image.png" alt="image" runat="server" />
```

This will automatically translate your src-value into a path which will resolve from your current location. However, there is one caveat. If you do it on pages which are included, asp.net may create an incorrect value here, as it could be morphed into

```
<img src="../images/image.png" alt="image" />
```

if you are a directory down. So if you include this result in a page in the application root folder, your value may not be correct. I have not seen a good way to work around this. It will, however, show you a warning if the file doesn't exist.

Alternatively, you may want to manually set the root path for such pages:

```
<img src="<%=Request.ApplicationPath %>/images/image.png" alt="image" />
```

which will transform into a path always coming from the root of the site:

```
<img src="/AppPath/images/image.png" alt="image" />
```

Obviously, this is a bit more verbose. Additionally, you will not be able to see any warnings if the referenced file does not exist, as it will be dynamically built.